# Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MyModel'. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[ASP.net, MVC, C#, Microsoft VS 2010 Professional]

This is a modificaiton of the MvcMovies ASP.net tutorial.

I'm trying to add a Controller to my 'Beacon' model, and when I do I get the following **error**:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for MvcMovie.Models.Beacon'.  Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
```

My options in the '**Add Controller**' dialog are:

```
Controller name: BeaconsController
Template: MVC Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework
Model Class: Beacon (MvcMovie.Models)
Data context class: BeaconDBContext (MvcMovie.Models)
```

My **Beacon.cs** Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Beacon
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection QueryString { get; set; }
    }

    public class BeaconDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Beacon> Beacons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My **connection strings**:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130610094827;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="BeaconDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Beacons.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have already successfully created a controller for the Movie class, which I have based all of the Beacon code off of.

Rebuilding the solution does not solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what line in your code gives you the error? can you post that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment your connection strings (especially `BeaconDBContext`) before adding controller.

I know that this is not best solution, but it is working (for me).